# Free downloads increases the position on paid ranking?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm wondering what happen's with the reviews and ranking positions if I change my app price tier from tier 1 (0.99) to "Free" for some days. I know that it will increase the downloads, but I'm interested to know if that downloads may affect (in the  positive way) my application's position on the paid ranking when I revert the changes to tier 1 again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is this:
There is no effect except for more attention. Therefore this could help for a short period.

But you will get bad comments. For some strange reason people will give you a bad review if the app doesn't do what they expected even if it is free. (This is my experience from the German App-Store. Could be different in other countries.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the way Apple ranks apps is secret. To be able to answer your question you probably have to work for Apple and if you do you're probably not allowed to.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.